# Creating File Geodatabase in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

In ArcGIS Desktop we are able to create a file geodatabase and also a feature class.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: QGIS can read this proprietary format, but you'll need ArcGIS to create one.

Comment: @DPSSpatial QGIS can write them as well if the (GDAL) [FileGDB driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html) and Esri FileGDB API is installed (it's the OpenFileGDB driver, that's read-only).

Comment: How do I do that? Are they plugins?

Comment: Just tested, with the Esri FileGDB support added. Works fine, it just appears as an option when you 'save as' a layer.

Answer (score 1):

<s>As far as I know there is no way to create a file geodatabese (esri format) with qgis</s>  Edit : see comment below.

You may only read or read/write a file geodatabase (depending on what driver you have as said in the comment below your question)

The closest approximation of a file geodatabe in qgis would be to use GeoPackage or Spatialite (the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228210/using-geopackage-instead-of-spatialite-and-vice-versa) give more detail on these format). If you need to keep compatibility between qgis and arcgis these two format are supported in arcmap from version 10.2

Comment: I just used QGIS 3.2 with the appropriate FileGDB driver installed and chose the Export - Save Features As dialog box dropdown, selected ESRI FileGDB, typed in a file name and layer name but didn't point it to an existing GDB, just a folder.  It created an GDB with the file name and a feature class with the layer name within it.